# Compare 2 arrays of objects check for value that matches

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do we set the checkbox on the table as checked by default if there is match in 2 objects ? . I am having 2 objects 1 is selectedNewUser array of object and transactionUserTable.data array of objects which is from the api.

I want to compare if each emailAddress in transactionUserTable.data array of objects has match on emailAddress of selectedNewUser array of object if there is match or emailAddress equal then set checkbox value as checked.

Can anyone help me how can this be possible ? If anyone has any solution or ideas. Thank you and have a great day.

Compare each object of selectedNewUser  emailAddress to transactionUserTable.data emailAddress

#newly added users

```
selectedNewUser = [
    {
        "emailAddress": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "aa",
        "lastName": "aa",
        "phoneNumber": "232",
        "companyName": "bb",
        "title": "CEO",
        "roleId": 7,
        "associatedAccount": "WLGRN",
        "accountId": 4,
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Architect",
                "isShow": true,
                "transactionRoleId": 12
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Construction Project Director",
                "isShow": true,
                "transactionRoleId": 11
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "bbb@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "bb",
        "lastName": "vv",
        "phoneNumber": "34",
        "companyName": "test",
        "title": "CEO",
        "roleId": 7,
        "associatedAccount": "WLGRN",
        "accountId": 4,
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Architect",
                "isShow": true,
                "transactionRoleId": 12
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Construction Project Director",
                "isShow": true,
                "transactionRoleId": 11
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

#html code for checkbox

```
 <div class="table" [ngStyle.gt-md]="{'overflow': 'auto'}">
        
        <mat-table [dataSource]="transactionUserTable.dataSource" [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}" matMultiSort
            (matSortChange)="transactionUserTable.onSortEvent()">
            <!-- action Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action - Checkbox</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" fxLayoutAlign="center center">

                    <mat-checkbox [checked]="userSelectedStatus(item)" color="primary" [disableRipple]="true"
                        (change)="appendUserList($event,item)"></mat-checkbox>
                        
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

#Code that pulls list of users

```
private _transactionUserPageEvent() {
    this.isTransactionUserLoading = true;
    this.transactionUserTable.data = [];
    this._userProfileService.getUserProfileTableDropdown(
      this.accountId,
      this.transactionUserTable.pageIndex + 1,
      this.transactionUserTable.pageSize,
      this.searchTransactionUserInput.nativeElement.value,
      this.transactionUserTable.sortParams,
      this.transactionUserTable.sortDirs
    )
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isTransactionUserLoading = false)
      )
      .subscribe({
        error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        next: res => {
          console.log("new users"  , this.selectedNewUser)
          this.transactionUserTable.totalElements = res.totalItemCount;
          this.transactionUserTable.data = res.items as UserProfileDropdownDto[];
          this.totalData = res.totalItemCount;
          this.currentDisplayedData = res.lastItemOnPage;
        },
        complete: noop
      });
  }
```

#Sample data of list of users from api (transactionUserTable.data)

```
[
    {
        "id": 90085,
        "fullName": "1a 1a",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "1a",
        "lastName": "1a",
        "emailAddress": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "fsdfsd",
        "companyName": "test",
        "title": "CEO",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "08/08/2021 11:20:25 pm",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
    },
    {
        "id": 90086,
        "fullName": "1a 1bb",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "1a",
        "lastName": "1bb",
        "emailAddress": "bbb@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "32423",
        "companyName": "dcbvc",
        "title": "vsvfd",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "08/08/2021 11:25:59 pm",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
    },
    {
        "id": 90084,
        "fullName": "1aaa aaa",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "1aaa",
        "lastName": "aaa",
        "emailAddress": "1aaa@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "asdas",
        "companyName": "dfvdf",
        "title": "CEO",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "08/08/2021 10:32:49 pm",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
    },
    {
        "id": 40108,
        "fullName": "1aaaa@gmail.com 1aaaa@gmail.com",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "1aaaa@gmail.com",
        "lastName": "1aaaa@gmail.com",
        "emailAddress": "1aaaa@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "1",
        "companyName": "1aaaa@gmail.com",
        "title": "1aaaa@gmail.com",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "06/08/2021 1:22:50 pm",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
    },
    {
        "id": 70083,
        "fullName": "23 asdasd",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "23",
        "lastName": "asdasd",
        "emailAddress": "asdasasdas",
        "phoneNumber": "adasda",
        "companyName": "asdasd",
        "title": "assdasda",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "08/08/2021 7:28:05 pm",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UserProfileDropdownDto` add a property called `checked` and default it to `false` when you initialise it. Then in your `subscribe` of `getUserProfileTableDropdown` loop through `res.items`

```
res.items.forEach(item => {
  if(item.emailAddress && selectedNewUser.findIndex((x: any) => x.emailAddress === item.emailAddress) !== -1){
    item.checked = true;
  }
});
```

Then update your mat-checkbox code as:

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="item.checked" color="primary" [disableRipple]="true" (change)="appendUserList($event,item)"></mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: What is this issue sir , Property 'emailAddress' does not exist on type 'BaseModel'.ts(2339)

Comment: I'm not sure. Where is `BaseModel.ts` being used and what is it's structure?

Comment: How is it being used in the code that you have posted in your question?

Comment: I did not use the BasedModel on the component , I dont know why it is being called

Comment: You will have to debug it, there is no way way to answer this without looking at the code.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HqPPja8 , I think because there is a global handler for basedmodel which as you can see the items : BaseModel[];

Comment: Yeah but why is it expecting an `emailAddress` attribute in `baseModel.ts`?

Comment: because we are trying to access the items ? which is on baseModel ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6c13ANr , this is the data when I tried to  console.log("res" , res)

Comment: But items is of type `UserProfileDropdownDto`

Comment: I also called the PageModel on the service https://imgur.com/a/6c13ANr

Comment: But on the service I used the pagemodel https://imgur.com/a/ZLWlro4

Comment: Can you share your code somehow? It's really difficult to understand otherwise.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/free-vicovb? Hi , please check this Sir

Comment: I still cant access the data , still the same issue

Comment: The code is still incomplete as I can't see either `PagedModel` or `BaseModel` being accessed in the provided code.

Comment: the pagemodel was accessed through the service , if you check getUserProfileTableDropdown service

Comment: Yes Sir , but I have another problem https://imgur.com/a/DiZMYjs , I got this error on my this.selectedNewUser

Comment: Property 'emailAddress' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)

Comment: Check `this.selectedNewUser`, looks like it doesn't have a property called `emailAddress`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MldPNP5 it has sir , this is the proof